# huggingface EncoderDecoderModel has no attribute 'from_encoder_decoder_pretrained'

Tags: huggingface-transformers

I tried the examples in https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/v4.3.2/src/transformers/models/encoder_decoder/modeling_encoder_decoder.py, however, I got the AttributeError that type object 'EncoderDecoderModel' has no attribute 'from_encoder_decoder_pretrained'. How to address this problem?

Comment: Which version are you using? Also please add the code you are executing directly to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you just need to reinstall transformers. I encountered same problem, the reason is when I install transformers with pip, my memory run out.